# Count checked checkboxes within a query

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

How do I count checked checkboxes within a [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) in Google sheets (this is part of a group query where I want to count checked checkboxes in column B for each value of column A grouped by column A)?

Comment: @player0 How do I do that without sharing my gmail account?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103857/how-do-i-transfer-a-copy-of-google-sheets-to-someone

Comment: @player0 Here is a copy: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mJ8SXgdc-gH4bsx8DQT70Pnh3977B1Q46lngCFB4aho/copy

Comment: sheet is private. in top right of your sheet there is a green SHARE button. you will need to set it on from "Private" to "Anybody with link can view" - otherwise no one can access your spreadsheet ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:A\ B:B*1}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This gives me #ERROR!

Comment: Still a parse error. I'd like to send you a copy of the document. How is this possible without sharing my gmail account?

Comment: Thank you very much. What does the backslash do and where is this colon notation explained?

Comment: \ is equivalent of a comma , for non-US spreadsheets. it means to put column A next to column B in array { }. and as always its not explained anywhere.