# Count checked checkboxes within a query without ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Yesterday I learned what [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59751416/count-checked-checkboxes-within-a-query) what to write into cell C1 to get the little table seen in the added screenshot to get the table C1:D4. It's

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:A\ B:B*1};"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"))
```

Can you explain why you need the `ARRAYFORMULA` function there? Is there a way to simply manipulate my query in C6

```
=query(A:B;"select A,count(B) where A is not null group by A")
```

to get the same result? So I only want to manipulate the query string `"select A,count(B) where A is not null group by A"`. I don't want to add an additional `ARRAYFORMULA`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Array formula need because it has any process to Array B:B*1

Comment: Have you considered using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) with an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) trigger? It would offer more flexibility than using formulas.

Answer (score 1):

The arrayformula was needed to convert the boolean values (true when checked, false when unchecked) in the range B:B to numbers (0 and 1).

For a solution without Arrayformula, try

```
=query(A:B; "Select A, count(B) where B = true group by A")
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes, in my given example this works. But there are two problems with your solution. First: In case there is no single box checked for a value, it is omitted instead of a 0. Second: This is part of a bigger query where I need the other lines as well. For example I want to have a third column in which all items are counted (not only the checked ones).

Comment: In that case, keep using the solution with the arrayformula(). It should allow you to have additional counts of other columns.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayFormula is needed because of this multiplication: `B:B*1` and that is needed to convert `TRUE`/`FALSE` into `1`/`0`. and after you convert it into `1`/`0` you can "sum" it which sounds like summing but it's still counting coz you don't have a bigger value than 1.

your formula in C6 counts all checkboxes regardless if they are checked or unchecked